Simple Voltage Divider w/ Diodes

I'm looking at the pictured circuit, and I want to find \$V_\mathrm {out}\$ in the case that the diodes are on (\$V_\mathrm {out} >= 2\,V_\mathrm {in}\$). We are assuming ideal diodes. It seems like it should be a somewhat simple problem, but I've gotten stuck on it. I can see using simulations of the Thevenin equivalent that there is a further drop in voltage when the diodes are placed across the circuit, but I'm not able to develop and expression to explain this. I'm particularly looking for an expression of \$V_\mathrm {out}\$ as a function of \$V_\mathrm {in}\$, \$R_\mathrm 1\$, \$R_\mathrm 2\$, and \$V_\mathrm {out}\$, I'm not looking for any sort of numerical approximations.

what do you think the output voltage is? ... think about different resistor values,  and how they affect the output voltage if the diodes are not connected

"in the case that the diodes are on" - when silicon diodes are "on" they drop about 0.6V to 0.7V depending on how hard they are on (i.e. how much current is flowing through them).

Depends on the diodes. Si, Ge, LED's all have exponential V/A curves in forward direction, effectively actin as voltage regulators. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode for some.

Here's how to perform the computation. RS, ISAT, and ETA are parameters for the diode. VT is the thermal voltage. N is the number of series diodes. VCC is the voltage rail. The LTspice simulation text shows 'n' where I should have written ETA. My apologies on that possible confusion.

To find Vout just take Vth and subtract the product of the computed diode current times the sum of Rth and RS. I compute 1.27141 and LTspice shows 1.27489. Close enough. If you search the scholarly literature, you will readily find similar formulas discussed and developed for you. They have some theoretical application. But you must be familiar with these methods to find them yourself. (Spice will use different methods to get very similar results.)

Ideal diode models using a fixed voltage drop concept only work over a very tiny range of diode current. But the LambertW approach works over many orders of magnitude. For example: when VCC=1, IDcalc=220 nA, IDspice=218 nA; when VCC=10, IDcalc=3.118 mA, IDspice=3.116 mA; when VCC=100, IDcalc=43.73 mA, IDspice=43.71 mA. Almost six orders of current magnitude range. Just want to make sure that you understand these devices will pass currents even when only very tiny voltages are applied. And knowing that fact can be very important to keep in mind, while not always being needed, either.

Big "why" premable first, for the TLDR scroll to the bottom.
The diodes will each have roughly 0.7V across them whenever current through them is positive. Whether that current is 1μA or 1mA, their voltage will remain in the vicinity of 0.7V, as can be seen if we plot a single diode's voltage vs. current:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

As you can see, even the smallest current causes voltage across the diode to rise to 0.6V, but the curve quickly flattens out. It continues to rise gently with current, but we often characterise diodes using the rule-of-thumb figure of 0.7V as their "plateau" voltage. Different diodes will have slightly different characteristics, but 0.7V is the accepted rule of thumb. Textbooks might use the figure 0.6V, particularly for currents under 1mA, but for back-of-the-envelope analyses, mostly we assume 0.7V.
This same behaviour can also be observed if instead of forcing current through the diode, we impose a voltage across it, and measure the resulting current:

simulate this circuit

Notice that voltage starts off negative in this plot, meaning that the anode starts off (to the left) with a lower potential than the cathode, so that the diode is "reverse biased". Voltage increases through zero, where anode and cathode potentials are equal, and continues to increase into the regime called "forward bias", where the anode is more positive than the cathode.
It's clear that the diode behaves like an open-circuit, passing negligible current until the voltage across it reaches about 0.7V, at which point it becomes extremely conductive. Another way to describe this behaviour is as follows: when you try to impose some voltage across a diode, one of two things can occur:

If the voltage you are imposing would have the anode at 0.7V or less positive with respect to its cathode, then diode current will be negligible, as if the diode isn't even there. Even the weakest source of potential difference would not struggle to impose such a potential difference across the diode.

If the voltage imposed would cause the anode to be 0.7V or more positive with respect to the cathode, then the diode will pass immense quantities of current, effectively fighting against the voltage source in an attempt to prevent a further rise in voltage.


I like the analogy of a 2V voltage source being a rigid rod of length 2m, and a diode being a piece of rope of length 0.7m. Imagine the struggle between them, were their ends to be joined. Something has to break.
We can build a source designed deliberately to safely lose the battle against the diode, when trying to produce +0.7V or more. All we need do is artificially weaken the voltage source with a resistance:

simulate this circuit
Now as I sweep the source voltage V1 upwards from −4V, we can see how the fight evolves by observing potential \$V_D\$ at the diode's anode:

Up until \$V_1=+0.7V\$, there's no fight, because the diode does not pass significant current, happy to permit \$V_D=V_1\$. When V1 exceeds +0.7V the diode begins to insist, and wins due to "elasticity" provided by resistor R1, and \$V_D\$ remains "clamped" at +0.7V. Picture the resistor as a piece of elastic, in the rod+rope analogy.

TLDR
This picture differs slightly from your problem, in that you have two resistors, and two diodes. Ignoring the diodes for the moment, \$V_{IN}\$, \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ can be replaced with their Thevenin equivalent, where:
$$ R_{TH}= R_1 \parallel R_2\ $$
$$ V_{TH} = V_{IN}\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} $$

simulate this circuit
Now insert the diodes:

simulate this circuit
The two diodes, end to end are "ropes" with a combined "length" of \$2 \times 0.7m = 1.4m\$. By my analogy, a rod \$V_{TH}\$ would have to exceed 1.4m in length for the elastic of \$R_{TH}\$ to begin stretching, beyond which the diode ropes' ends would remain clamped at 1.4m apart.
It remains to find the value of \$V_{IN}\$ that would produce the condition \$V_{TH}=+1.4V\$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
1.4 &= V_{IN}\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} \\ \\
V_{IN} &= 1.4\frac{R_1+R_2}{R_2}
\end{aligned}
$$
To test the theory, let's set \$R_1 = 200\Omega\$ and \$R_2 = 100\Omega\$. Without the diodes in place, the unconstrained output \$V_D\$ would be:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_D &= V_{IN}\frac{100}{100+200} \\ \\
&= \frac{V_{IN}}{3}
\end{aligned}
$$
The input voltage \$V_{IN}\$ which would just begin to evoke diode clamping would be:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{IN} &= 1.4\frac{200+100}{100} \\ \\
&= 4.2V
\end{aligned}
$$
We expect, then, for input voltages \$V_{IN}<+4.2V\$, the diodes offer no opposition to the input source, and output \$V_D=\frac{V_{IN}}{3}\$. When \$V_{IN} > +4.2V\$, then diodes are heavily conducting, clamping D to its maximum of \$V_D=+1.4V\$:

simulate this circuit


As a first-order approximation, the circuit has two possible states:

\$ V_{out} \ge 2V_{on}\$, in which case \$ V_{out}\$ is fixed by the diode conduction action and changing \$ V_{in}\$ only changes the current through diodes and \$ R_{1}\$.
\$ V_{out} < 2V_{on}\$, in which case \$ V_{out}\$ is derived from the voltage divider equation assuming negligible leakage in the diodes: \$ V_{out} = \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}V_{in}\$.

You need to solve for \$V_{out}\$ in both cases and see which answer is consistent with the initial assumption regarding the state of the diodes. More accurate solutions would need better models or approximations to the diode behavior.



as you can see the first part of the circuit did not act as a voltage regulator. Then the diodes or in parallel connection which makes them as positive clamper circuit. you can simulate as your own.
One diode is forward biased (with its anode at V out) and
cathode connected to ground.
The other diode is reverse biased (with its cathode at V out) and
its anode connected to ground.
This parallel connection allows each diode to conduct current in opposite directions, depending on the polarity of the voltage at the output node. This arrangement is commonly used in voltage clamping circuits, where each diode clamps the voltage in one direction.
